# Need to change Datagridview row color if checkbox is checked on Form Load

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

i have problem with dataset gridview on Form load procedure. I hava dataset as datagridview source and when I'm trying to change datagrid row color based on if statement if checkbox is checked nothing happens. If I used same code on some button-click procedure it all works fine.

Can anyone help me with this problem.

```
 da.Fill(ds, "customer")
    cnn.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("customer")


    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = True Then

            DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.MediumAquamarine
        Else
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.MistyRose
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: what language are you coding in

Comment: Its VB...ill add code above.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have this code in Form_Load. This only occur when the form starts the first time. Try instead to put the code in the DataGridView1.Paint event handler. That should do the trick.